# C# equivalent to SerializaAsString()?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have a proto file that describes a message:

```
message SharedData
{
  string instanceName = 1;
  string userName = 2;
  bytes data = 3;
  uint64 data_size = 4;
}
```

When serializing using c++, I can use

```
SharedData data_instance;
std::string string_data = someObject.SerializeAsString();
data_instance.set_data(stringData);
```

to save the object in the data field.

I'm trying to do the same in C#. The data field's type is **ByteString**. There is no SerializeAsString method available for objects. I tried using someObject.ToByteString() but the data is not interpreted correctly on the other side.

Is there a C# equivalent to SerializeAsString()?

Thanks

Comment: why do you have to serialize grpc message, doesn't the grpc library automatically do it for you?

Comment: Please check what format python is serializing data into with `SerializeAsString`.

Comment: I am not sure if this points in the right direction, but you can serialize objects to json strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken - the serialization that works is in c++, not python. I did not write this side. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The problem was that I kept an instance as a public variable and updated it. The correct way is to create a new object each time and use

```
someObject.ToByteString()
```

on the new object.

Now I'm trying to find a way to deserialize it in C#...